# Test dependencies of Maven parent POM not showing in Gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle

We have a Maven parent POM (project A) that contains all of the common dependencies for our microservices. We are now converting all of our microservices to Gradle, but we are having trouble getting the test dependencies of project A to show up in the Gradle projects.

When we compile the Gradle projects, we get a compileTestJava error because the Spring Boot test JAR cannot be found. We are importing the parent POM dependency in Gradle using the following code:

implementation (group: 'com.123.abc', name = 'parent-pom' version='1.0.0')
What are we doing wrong? How can we get the test dependencies of project A to show up in the Gradle projects?

Additional information:

The parent POM is packaged as a pom file and published to Artifactory.
The Gradle projects are using the Java plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven, transitive test dependencies are ignored. I guess the same is true for Maven.